Problema em retorno de dados JSON
Tenho uma aplicação em React e um JSON que recebe os dados, uso o "fetch" para fazer a requisição. O JSON não esta retornando 2 dados muito importantes para meu programa, ele apenas retorna as categorias e o id do projeto.
O "db.json" deveria também retornar os dados de "name" e "budget".
tentei forçar o retorno, mas não consegui nada. Peço ajuda
CODIGO:
CRIAÇÃO DE PROJETO:

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './NewProject.module.css';
import ProjectForm from '../project/ProjectForm';

function NewProject() {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

        function createPost( project ) {

        // initialize cost and services
        project.cost = 0
        project.services = []

        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/projects`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
             'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(project),
         })
             .then((resp) => resp.json())
             .then((data) => {
                 // redirect
                 navigate("/projects", {state: { message: "Projeto criado com sucesso!" }});
             })
             .catch(err => console.log(err))
     }
    return (
        <div className={styles.newproject_container}>
            <h1>Criar Projeto</h1>
            <p>Crie seu projeto para depois adicionar os serviços</p>
            <ProjectForm handleSubmit={createPost} btnText="Criar Projeto"/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default NewProject;

--DB.JSON

{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": "1a8c",
      "category": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Desenvolvimento"
      },
      "cost": 0,
      "services": []
    },
}

